# Does C# have something like Pascal record type?

Tags: c#, record

I just switched to C# from Pascal and i didn't find in C# something simillar to Pascal record type.
So in Pascal i have something like that:

```
Type StudentInfo = record
   Name: string; 
   LastName: string; 
   Age: integer; 
   Grade: byte; 
end;
```

How can i make something like this in C#?

Comment: You are asking a C# question, so take the time to explain what is it you are after, because not every C# developer knows Pascal. What makes a record special that a `class`, an `interface` or a `struct` doesn't give you?

Comment: [This site](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Pascal_for_CSharp_users) claims that you are looking for a `struct`, so I am not sure how much you searched

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried to use class. I found this code in internet: 
public class studentInfo
{
   public string StudentFName { get; }
   public string StudentMName { get; }
   public string StudentLName { get; }

   public studentInfo(string strFN, string strMN, string strLN)
   {
       StudentFName = strFN;
       StudentMName = strMN;
       StudentLName = strLN;
   }
}

Comment: @JackWalters: *"I tried to use class"* - What did you try, and what didn't work the way you expected it to?  It sounds like the question you've asked above is covering up the actual question you want to ask.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i will try to use struct. Thank you for your anwser.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Record is simply how Classes are implented in Pascal: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Record The only *possible* special rule might be that they can be runtime dynamic. That is not something C# (easily) supports, but there are workarounds for specific cases where you absolutely need it. The struct and class also use extremely similar syntax in any C-type langauge. In Native C++ it even used to be that the only differene between Struct and Class were the default accessor (public or private). So if you can write one, you should be able to write the other.

Comment: @Christopher: you remember incorrectly, or your encounters with Pascal were a very very long time ago. In Object Pascal, i.e. the mostly used dialects Delphi and Free Pascal, a *record* is a **value type** and thus the equivalent of a *struct*. In O.P., a *class* is a **reference** type, like in C#, and therefore the equivalent of a *class*. After all,the main designer of C#, Anders Hejlsberg, used to be one of the main designers of Delphi.

Comment: @Christopher: actually, in old non-object Pascal, records were value types too, but without methods or properties.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I am actually not remembering at all. My knowledge was literally limited to what I linked. The rest was asumptions. And in this case indeed a .NET struct would be a closer equivalent to record then class.

Comment: This **question** is not unclear at all. But the **answers and comments** seem to be written by people who don't have a clue about Pascal. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

in C# this is either a Class or Struct. Google will help you also :)

example:

```
struct StudentInfo {
   string name;
   string LastName;
   int Age;
   byte Grade;
}
```

Comment: *Records* are **value types**, so *struct* is correct, *class* is wrong. In Object Pascal, a *class* is also called a *class* and is a **reference type**.